# SUM of common divisors of pairs

Tags: algorithm, math

In this problem i want to find the sum of all common divisor of pairs. The pairs are formed as follows:

Given number N=3
Then the pair of numbers and there common divisors are as follows :

> - (1,1)=1 , (1,2)=1 , (1,3)=1
> - (2,2)=3 , (2,3)=1,
> - (3,3)=4 (common divisor of this pair is 1 and 3 so sum is 4)

**So the answer is sum of all common divisor i.e. 11.**

I observed some kind of series in this like

```
for 1 : 1 1 1 1 ....
for 2 : 3 1 3 1 ....
for 3:  4 1 1 4 ....
for 4 : 7 1 3 1 7 .....
for 5 : 6 1 1 1 1 6 ....
for 6 : 12 1 3 4 3 1 12 ....
```

So on

Can this question solved by using the above pattern?
 If **yes** than please help me by writeting a **pseudo code** for this.

Comment: All common divisors divide the GCD, which can be found very efficiently via the Euclidean algorithm. So -- find the GCD and then factor it. Even with a naïve factoring algorithm you should be able to do this in something like `O(log(n)*sqrt(n))`

Comment: Lalit, could you tell why your example is 2-dimensional? Is the answer a function of just single N such that  F(1) = 1, F(2) = 5, F(3) = 11? Or does it have some additional argument(s)?

Comment: Are you after an explanation of your table or after a way to compute that sum? See also: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=sum+common+divisors+pairs).

Answer (score 1):

In this answer I assume that what you are interested in is a simple function of single argument N. I think that it can be calculated in `O(N)` (assuming you don't go into long arithmetics area). Actually you can find the sequence at [OEIS A143127](http://oeis.org/A143127) where it is specified as

> Sum of k*d(k) over k=1,2,...,n, where d(k) is the number of divisors of k.

However it might be not that obvious, why that sequence is the right answer. To understand why, let's see what is the difference `F(N) - F(N-1)`.  Next `N` adds pairs `(i, N)` for `i` in range `[1, N]`. For each divisor `p` of `N` there will be `N/p` pairs that will add `p` to the sum. In other words each divisor adds exactly `N` to the sum. So if `d(N)` is number of divisors, together we get `N * d(N)` for all pairs `(i, N)`.

We can get more direct formula if we chage order of summation. Consider some fixed `N` and `m < N`. How many times `m` will be added as a common divisor of some pair? Well, it will be added for all pairs where both numbers are divided by `m`. There are `floor(N/m)` numbers that are divided by `m` among number up to `N`. And since we count only unique pairs, there will be `floor(N/m) * (floor(N/m) + 1) / 2` pairs each adding `m` to the sum. Adding it all up for all `m` we get `O(N)`-time formula

```
a(n) = sum_{m=1..N} m * floor(N/m) * (floor(N/m)+1)/2
```

OEIS provides a more complicated formula that seems to have `O(sqrt(N))` running time

```
a(n) = sum_{m=1..floor(sqrt(n))} m*(m+floor(n/m))*(floor(n/m)+1-m) - A000330(floor(sqrt(n)))
```

where

```
A000330(n) = n*(n+1)*(2*n+1)/6.
```

But I'm not sure how they got it. Still in my tests this formula produces correct results for first 30 values.